# How to pass object to MFC dialog

Tags: c++, class, object, mfc, dialog

I have a class named `IF`, in the header she has an object `deque <CMessage> m_messages` 
I need to write in the constructor "new" to this deque? how do I do this?

I need to pass this deque with data inside it to my dialog class and print it in "control list".  How do I pass the deque by reference to the dialog class?

Comment: Please just edit this question if you wish to re-phrase it.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the constructor of your dialog and pass it as reference to your deque, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: my constractor is: CMonitorDialog::CMonitorDialog(CWnd* pParent): CDialog(CMonitorDialog::IDD, pParent) i need to pass by referance "deque" HOW TO DO THAT?