# Pass object by reference

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass object to MFC dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470193/how-to-pass-object-to-mfc-dialog)

How to pass "deque" by reference? What to write in the h file and on the cpp file, the object needs to be pointer?

Comment: You already posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470193/how-to-pass-object-to-mfc-dialog

Comment: In C++, pointers and references are entirely different things.  The fact that references are normally implemented by using pointers internally has nothing to do with the language itself.

Comment: Pointers and references are different (though they are both used as "handles" to other objects). Read your C++ book.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is pretty vague, so:

```
void foo(const std::deque<int>& deque_by_ref)
{
    // ...
}
```